# Converting date-picker format in to numeric in android

Tags: android, datepicker

I am using date picker widget for my application. My application is having two input values in this format 01/01/2012 and 05/09/2012 respectively.

The date-picker widget is in this format dd-mm-yyyy **eg:- 01-jan-1990**

but i need to convert the above format in to 01/01/1990.

How to do this?

suggestions please!..

Comment: read the documentation for the widget. there are methods for getting values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see this example for [DatePicker](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-date-picker-example/). In that.. there is method `onDateSet` in that you are getting 3 int number..

just concate them `String dt = day+"/"+month+"/"+year`

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
DatePicker dp; 
... 
String result = dp.getDayOfMonth()+"/"+dp.getMonth()+"/"+dp.getYear();
```

Comment: Your answer would be considerably better if you could explain _why_ this would work.

Comment: Can you tell me,why your are getting the values in String...Usually date should be in numeric only right...So in that be the case,can you tell me how to right the code regards to numeric

Comment: @prabu Do you want a String containing 01/01/1990 or do you want a long (containing ms since epoch)?

Comment: @Ben I could copy the doc from DatePicker or explain something about string concatenation but I guess that's not what you were expecting so I guess I'm missing something.

Comment: @Ben I do agree that my answer is incomplete since it won't format eg "1" to "01" etc.